# Search and copy row data VBA

Tags: regex, excel, vba

I have some code that runs a search on the second sheet, copy's the matching row data into the specified location the first sheet.
Currently It grabs the first row and copies the information into 'Work Listings" sheet, I A) need it to loop for other rows with matching names in the column A and paste the matching data underneath, and if no matching names are found in column A to search column B and copy the matching row data.

Here is what I have so far, which works, I just cant wrack my brains on how to get the loops to work. Any help would be great!!

```
Sub Filldata()
Dim nxtRow As Integer
ActiveSheet.Unprotect
With Worksheets("Destinations").Range("A:A")

    Set c = .Find(Worksheets("Week Listings").Cells(17, 3).Value, LookIn:=xlValues)
    If c Is Nothing Then
        Range("A20") = "Not Found"
        Range("B20") = "Not Found"
        LCSearch.Hide
        Select Case MsgBox("ESA code entered is invalid, please check. If it aligns with that shown on the order, take action to have the order corrected.", vbOKOnly + vbDefaultButton1, "Error")
            Case vbOK
        End Select
    Else
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect
        mydest = c.Row
              Range("A20") = Worksheets("Destinations").Cells(mydest, 1)
              Range("B20") = Worksheets("Destinations").Cells(mydest, 2)
              Range("C20") = Worksheets("Destinations").Cells(mydest, 3)
              Range("D20") = Worksheets("Destinations").Cells(mydest, 4)
              Range("E20") = Worksheets("Destinations").Cells(mydest, 5)
              Range("F20") = Worksheets("Destinations").Cells(mydest, 6)
              Range("G20") = Worksheets("Destinations").Cells(mydest, 7)
              Range("H20") = Worksheets("Destinations").Cells(mydest, 8)
              LCSearch.Hide
              ActiveSheet.Unprotect
    End If

End With
Worksheets("Week Listings").Range("A20").Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Not so clear what worksheets you are referring as First and Second, but from your code I believe first is <kbd>Destinations</kbd> and second is <kbd>Week Listings</kbd>.

Below code assumes you are only interested in value in <kbd>'Week Listings'!C17</kbd> and write findings from <kbd>'Week Listings'!A20</kbd>, only search columns A, B in **Destinations**:

```
Sub Filldata()
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim oWS1 As Worksheet, oWS2 As Worksheet
    Dim oRngTmp As Range, oRngSearchFor As Range, oRngSearchData As Range, oRngWriteTo As Range
    Dim i As Long, sTmp As String

    Set oWS1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Destinations")
    Set oWS2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Week Listings")
    oWS2.Unprotect

    ' Search for 'Week Listings'!C17
    Set oRngSearchFor = oWS2.Cells(17, 3)
    oRngSearchFor.Value = UCase(oRngSearchFor.Value)

    ' Start cell for writing found data
    Set oRngWriteTo = oWS2.Range("A20")
    sTmp = ""
    ' Setup Search Data, first try Column A
    Set oRngSearchData = oWS1.Columns("A")
    Set oRngTmp = oRngSearchData.Find(oRngSearchFor.Value, LookIn:=xlValues)
    If Not oRngTmp Is Nothing Then
        ' Store first found Address
        sTmp = oRngTmp.Address
        Do
            ' Copy A:H of the matched row to "oRngWriteTo"
            For i = 1 To 8
                oRngWriteTo.Offset(0, i - 1).Value = oWS1.Cells(oRngTmp.Row, i).Value
            Next
            ' Move "oRngWriteTo" to next row
            Set oRngWriteTo = oRngWriteTo.Offset(1, 0)
            Set oRngTmp = oRngSearchData.FindNext(after:=oRngTmp)
        Loop While oRngTmp.Address <> sTmp
    End If

    ' Setup Search Data, next try Column B
    Set oRngSearchData = oWS1.Columns("B")
    Set oRngTmp = oRngSearchData.Find(oRngSearchFor.Value, LookIn:=xlValues)
    If Not oRngTmp Is Nothing Then
        ' Store first found Address
        sTmp = oRngTmp.Address
        Do
            ' Copy A:H of the matched row to "oRngWriteTo"
            For i = 1 To 8
                oRngWriteTo.Offset(0, i - 1).Value = oWS1.Cells(oRngTmp.Row, i).Value
            Next
            ' Move "oRngWriteTo" to next row
            Set oRngWriteTo = oRngWriteTo.Offset(1, 0)
            Set oRngTmp = oRngSearchData.FindNext(after:=oRngTmp)
        Loop While oRngTmp.Address <> sTmp
    End If
    If sTmp = "" Then
        MsgBox "No results Found for " & oRngSearchFor.Value, vbInformation + vbOKOnly
    End If
    oWS2.Protect
    LCSearch.Hide ' Hide UserForm
    ' Clean Up
    Set oRngTmp = Nothing
    Set oRngSearchData = Nothing
    Set oRngSearchFor = Nothing
    Set oRngWriteTo = Nothing
    Set oWS1 = Nothing
    Set oWS2 = Nothing
End Sub
```

---

Above code will work for any string and not exact text. E.G. "Hamilton " is not find when searching for "Hamilton" (spaces before and after text are ignored).

Comment: Hi Thanks yes you are right, sorry for being a little vague.

Comment: I gave your code a run but debugs out on oRngWriteTo.Offset(0, i - 1).Value = oWS1.Cells(oRngTmp.Row, i)

Comment: sorry, forgot to put **.Value** at the end of them. updated solution.

Comment: Working great, Thanks heaps!!!!! Only thing its not doing now is adding citys that are listed twice onto the next line.

Comment: Welcome user, "adding citys that are listed twice onto the next line"? I don't know what columns are they. Next line as in `Worksheets("Week Listings").Cells(18, 3)`? If this answers your original question, please mark answered to close the question.

Comment: Hi any chance I could get some help on the Loop for column A & B, The search works however it seems to just store/display the first row in column A or B, I was hoping to print all rows with matching values. EG: Column A; holds main city names, however that city name may exist more than once, as it exists in different states eg "hamilton" as there is a city of that name in every state of Australia. So I need all rows that have that name to appear "Week Listings".

Comment: Do you mean all used cells in `Worksheets("Destinations")`? If so, replace `Set oRngSearchData = oWS1.Columns("A")` with `Set oRngSearchData = oWS1.UsedCells` and remove the Column B portion. Printing results will need to set from **'Week Listings'!A20** to the last result. Note that there isn't a clear old data before the search.

Comment: Hey patricK, What I mean is if I do a search with the current VBA code, the results for the search are displayed in cell A20, however it only shows the first result of the search, I need it to also display the other matching rows. best example i search hamilton: into cell A20 is the first matching result, however as the city exists twice I would also like the that displayed in the next row down "A21" etc

Comment: If it would help I can send you a copy

Comment: Hmm seem to get a run time error 1004 for oRngWriteTo.Offset(0, i - 1).Value = oWS1.Cells(oRngTmp.Row, i).Value

Comment: tested and improved version replied to your email... :)